# replacing characters in python without replace function

Tags: python

```py
def replace_characters(the_string):

    new_string = ''

    for i in range(len(the_string)-1):

        slice_string = the_string[i: i + 2]

        if slice_string == 'ph':
            new_string += 'b

        else:
            new_string = the_string

    print(new_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_string = input('What string do you want to process?')
    replace_characters(the_string)
```

for output if I have a input of ph, I'm able to get ϕ, but not when the string is longer like lets say a phone. I would like to get ϕone

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @TomKarzes, then I get a output of ϕphonephonephone

Comment: `.split()` your input into a list, then for each `word` you take from it, you want to check whether `word.lower() == ` your special characters (say `"ph"`). Get rid of `the_string[i: i + 2]` because it's too close to `word.startswith(...)` which is the root of your problem.

Comment: A problem I see is you're slicing 2 chars and appending them while your loop is only incrementing by 1.. so you'll get a lot of repetition.

Comment: I see two problems: (1) `else` replaces all string but it should add one char like `new_string += the_string[i]`. (2) using `for`- you can't skip second char from `ph` and it may use `h` with next char, or it will add it to new string. BTW: third problem - using `len(the_string)-1` it may skip last char.

Comment: thank you @furas, fixing the else statement did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems

(1) `else` replaces all string but it should add one char like `new_string += the_string[i]`.

(2) using `for`-loop you can't skip second char from `ph` and it may use `h` with next char, or it will add it to new string. If you would have statemant which changes `ho` then it would tread `pho` as as `ph` + `ho`

(3) using `len(the_string)-1` it may skip last char.

My version

```
def replace_characters(the_string):

    new_string = ''

    i = 0
    while i < len(the_string):

        slice_string = the_string[i: i+2]

        if slice_string == 'ph':
            new_string += '\u03d5'
            i += 2  

        elif slice_string == 'th':
            new_string += '\u03b8'
            i += 2 

        elif slice_string == 'ch':
            new_string += '\u03c7'
            i += 2

        else:
            new_string += the_string[i]
            i += 1

    print(new_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_string = 'phone'
    replace_characters(the_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues was the lines in this format:

```
new_string += '\u03d5'
```

The proper thing to have would be this

```
def replace_characters(the_string):
    new_string = ''

    for i in range(len(the_string)-1):

        slice_string = the_string[i: i + 2]

        if slice_string == 'ph':
            new_string = the_string[:i]+'\u03d5'+the_string[i+2:]
            the_string = new_string

        elif slice_string == 'th':
            new_string = the_string[:i]+'\u03b8'+the_string[i+2:]
            the_string = new_string

        elif slice_string == 'ch':
            new_string = the_string[:i]+'\u03c7'+the_string[i+2:]
            the_string = new_string

        else:
            new_string = the_string
        print(new_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_string = input('What string do you want to process?')
    replace_characters(the_string)
```

This way you also account for having multiple replacable values in the string.
For example :

```
What string do you want to process? phonche
ϕonche
ϕonche
ϕonche
ϕonχe
ϕonχe
ϕonχe
```

cheers :)